# Gstreamer: Is there plugin to increase audio volume of an audio source

Tags: audio, gstreamer

As above. Want to artificially  increase the loudness of a microphone recording of live scene. Have used the following plugins volume

```
 pulsesrc volume=8.0 \
    ! audioconvert \
    ! audioresample \
    ! volume volume=1.0 \
    ! audio/x-raw,rate=8000,channels=1,depth=8,format=S16LE \
    ! filesink location=record.wav
```

Have also tried audioamplify but seem like both have the raw recorded volume as the upper limit
in loudness

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The `volume` property of the `volume` element has a range from `0.0` to `10.0` while `1.0` represents 100% volume.